# How to make #future calls on Celluloid pool blocking?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, celluloid

I'm trying to create pool of workers which will perform some HTTP communication and compute values using results.

My initial approach looks like this:

```
class Worker
  include Celluloid
  ...
end

pool = Worker.pool(size: 5)

collection.map do
  arguments = compute_arguments
  pool.future.external_call(arguments)
end.inject(0) { |acc, el| acc + el.value }
```

It works more or less as expected — it seems like 5 concurrent processes are running `external_call` simultaneously.

The problem is, that for the code is not "streamlined", and precomputes all `arguments` (these computations are much faster than `external_call`) up-front. I'd like my code to wait in the first block, since pool is unable to provide future that will start it's work immediately.

`future` is not waiting for pool to release worker (nor is `async`). How can I make these calls wait for free worker in pool (i.e. perform something like `get` from pool which would return worker that is ready to use)?